# Does AWS CloudSearch allow searching multiple domains in the same query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

My team's application has numerous data types across 11 tables in our application database. To implement an efficient keyword search across specific fields on all of these types, we are exploring AWS CloudSearch as one option. Our intention is to return relevant results across all record types for a given keyword search.

My understanding is that each record type (each table) would end up in a separate CloudSearch domain. If that is the case, does the service allow for a search across multiple domains? Or would multiple requests need to be submitted and combined after they return?

Please correct me if I am mistaken at any point above. I have searched the CloudSearch documentation generally for a hint about this, but have not come to any conclusion.

Side Notes:

Our alternative is a non-self-hosted ElasticSearch service, which would solve this problem. However, our application ecosystem is currently hosted exclusively within a handful of AWS services. The advantages and disadvantages to CloudSearch vs ElasticSearch are unclear in this regard. If an endorsement can be made with a technical reason relating to the above, I would appreciate it. Though, I respect that this is not the place for a general pros vs cons discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each Cloudsearch query is for data within a single domain.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's true that you can only query data from a single domain, where a domain is a data structure.

However, you could flatten all the tables into a single domain, add a "type" index field, and when querying add the specific type as a filter.